# Vue + Laravel 5.4 + Mix - "Cannot Get /"

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

I downloaded started with a Larvavel + Vue component called [vuetable-2](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-with-laravel-5.4) (very nice BTW).

Firstly, `php artisan serve` works. Everything is fine, except that it doesn't hot deploy changes to .vue files.

I've finally got `npm run hot` to work, however, when go to the page I get the browser message:

**Cannot Get /**

*Actions Taken:*

- Checked my dependencies, as far as I can see, all are correct.
- Deleted node_modules and rebuit (three times now) `npm install`
- Created a separate test project to confirm Vue does hot reload (it
  does)

I suspect the problem is some configuration somewhere, but for the life of me, can't figure out where.

The only odd thing I've found is, the `webpack.config.js` says it will use `port 3000`, yet, the only port that seems to be working is either **8000 when using artisan**, or **run dev hot uses 8080** which produces the message above.

However, if I make changes to the files, I get the nice Laravel Mix toast telling the build was successful or not, but can't see them in the browser. The `webpack.config.js` also has the correct build path, being `public/`.

---

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=./webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=./webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=./webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=./webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.4",
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.4",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "vue-loader": "^11.1.4",
    "vue-style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "vue-events": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-masked-input": "^0.4.1",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "vuetable-2": "^1.3.1"
  }
}
```

The `webpack.config.js` file is unchanged from the standard one installed.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone that still looking for answers

Add this to a webpack.mix.js file

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.webpackConfig({
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '*': 'http://localhost:8000'
        }
    }
});
```

Run the backend server (`php artisan serve`) and then `npm run hot`. This will proxy all frontend requests to the backend so files can be processed correctly. More information [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server#devserverproxy)

With that said, `npm run hot` should work without developer modification.

source https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2057

Comment: I've tried this, but it's gives me 404 | Not Found page of Laravel. First, I've putted this code in `webpack.mix.js` file, then run `php artisan serve` and then run `npm run hot`, but no luck!! Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing the path to cross-env...
Try with this:

```
"dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"prod": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```

I've deleted your `"dev": "npm run development",` and `"prod": "npm run production",`. If you want to change commands just change them.

Hope It works.

Comment: Hi @Angus Simons, thanks for replying. I'm still learning all this stuff, so thanks for the pointers. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same result. But you've given me a new avenue to investigate.

Comment: Thanks I will re-read it. I added a bunch of things via NPM so I guess somewhere I screwed something up.

Comment: @Anthony Have you installed webpack globally?

Comment: No haven't. Should I do that? I'm still a little unclear about the implications of global npm modules vs. project ones.

Comment: i think there's something going on with Laravel (I'm using 5.4 on Linux). Just to test, I did a totally new install with `laravel new Project`. Then `npm install`, followed by `npm run dev`, which did a build, but failed to start a web service. Then tried `npm run hot`, which shows the build service and web server running, but again, same message: **Cannot get "/"**

Comment: Also on a fresh install you have to set `/dist` folder for cross-env cause they changed it.

Comment: Thanks @Angus, forgive the dumb question how/where do I do that?

Comment: @Anthony in your package.json on the main folder of your laravel project and install npm and webpack globally

Comment: Hi @Angus, already updated `package.json` as per your original comments. Also already installed webpack and npm globally. Still the same issue. :-|

Rather than keep bugging you, is there a link you can refer me to? I've searched but not found one that meets my case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141776/discussion-between-angus-simons-and-anthony).

Comment: that dosn't halp to me

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko we didn't resolve the issue on the chat. I'm still have the same problem.

Comment: After brief research, I think webpack-dev-server won't work out of the box, with laravel, in part because index.php is in /public, not /. I found [this post](https://m.dotdev.co/using-webpack-2-hmr-in-laravel-development-2f632d6d06c6) which may help, although I haven't tried it.